# Why is the same ios code on iphone6 and iphone6s memory is not the same increase?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory

I have a tableview and the cells have a picture, the picture width is the screen width, and height is the screen width.

A picture size is about 900k, so it is big.

when I run this code and scroll, on iPhone 6 memory is 44M, but on iPhone 6S+ plus memory is 370M or more, I don't why.

Comment: Have you used the memory instruments tool to check your memory usage?

Comment: yes ,i have see, and 400M is get from when i run, zhe xcode left bar ,the first six buttons, i can see zhe cpu , memory, energy impact, disk ,network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone 6 is having  Apple A8 ,64-bit Architecture &in iPhone 6S+ having Apple A9, 3rd Gen , 64-bit Architecture.
In Apple A9, 3rd Gen , 64-bit runtime, many data types used by Cocoa Touch frameworks (as well as the Objective-C language itself) have increased in size or have stricter memory alignment rules.Also the  runtime requires proper function prototypes to be used when making function calls. This is the reason for slight difference in your memory.
Thanks

Comment: thanks, i just don't how to care it, because it can make my memory to 400M, is too big, and is OK? it means i don't care memory later?

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 6 use @2x images when 6+ uses @3x.
So it is quite normal than memory use is greater on 6+ than on 6.

Question is, is the ratio 44M vs 370M logical ?

Not really, it should be around 66M. as @Paulw11 said, using instrument may give you an explanation.

( Maybe your are scaling the image, and it use lot of memory to do that, try to export an @3x version of the image and try again )